# Restrict Layer Style getting saved in QGIS project table in PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layers, style

As postgres admin , I have created a layer and styled the same in QGIS AND saved the style in postgres. When another user uses the same project(user have been given the grant to access the project) and changes the styling(color of the feature) and saves the project , the default style gets changed.
How do I stop the user from saving the project with the style?

Comment: The users should have different access privileges to the QGIS project / style tables - they should only be able to READ, not write/modify.